# SSH to CNAME'd tor hidden service

Tags: ssh, dns, tor

TLDR: I can SSH the onion address, but not the hostname that's CNAME'd to it.

I have the SSH server running as a Tor service, but I don't want to have to remember the onion address. I know I could just add the name to my SSH client config, but the purpose of this is to be able to access my computer when I'm borrowing someone else's, and obviously I don't want to mess too much with other people's settings. (And yes, these other computers are actually likely to have Tor already installed.) So I set up a hostname with a CNAME record pointing to the onion address. If I do `torify ssh myaddress.onion`, it works fine, but `torify ssh mydomain.com` results in:

```
1565911820 ERROR torsocks[31652]: Unable to resolve. Status reply: 4 (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:683)
ssh: Could not resolve hostname mydomain.com: Non-recoverable failure in name resolution
```

(And no, I did not literally type `mydomain.com`; the error is edited.)

Doing `dig -t CNAME mydomain.com` does return the onion address. All of my testing so far has been on the host machine itself (LUbuntu 18.04.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a failure in your understanding how DNS works, combined with the fact that `.onion` isn't a valid TLD in public DNS.  Let me give you a crash-course in CNAME resolution, as well as a solution for you to try to 'alias' this on your side of things.

**DNS CNAME Resolution**

DNS CNAME records are called *aliases*.  They act as a pointer saying "This domain is an alias for this other domain, resolve that domain and go to that destination."

If I have a domain `example1.com` with an A record of 1.2.3.4 which is my actual server, and `example2.com` set as a CNAME of `example1.com`, then when I go to `example2.com` DNS will see that the DNS records for `example2.com` for A record resolution depend on the record of `example1.com`.  This works in NORMAL DNS because it's publicly addressed and able to be looked up.

The CNAME destination isn't really "shared" as the DNS lookup result for a DNS lookup that is being done, only the resulting A/AAAA record is cared about and since there can't be one for `.onion` it fails to DNS properly, and fails.  Explanation below.

**Why ONION Resolution Fails**

CNAME records are **NOT** the same as Tor ONION addresses.  When you look up a CNAME record against a `.onion` address in standard DNS, it hard-fails.  This is because in public DNS, `.onion` isn't addressable and isn't a valid TLD.

CNAME records also **do not** 'resolve' to the alias address in the format of a 'redirect' like you think - the CNAME will only properly *resolve* if the destination of the CNAME pointer actually can return a public DNS record.  Because it's a `.onion` it never will so it either NXDOMAINs or SERVFAILs on the lookups.

This is why you get the error you're getting.

**How can I get this to work then?**

By 'cheating' and configuring your SSH config a bit.

Try adding this section to your `~/.ssh/config` file (create the file if it doesn't exist):

```
Host mydomain.com
    Hostname myaddress.onion
```

Then try to SSH again to `mydomain.com`.  It *should* repoint this to your `.onion` address behind the scenes.

However, **DO NOT** rely on DNS to point domains to `.onion` addresses - they don't work in public DNS for domains.

Comment: I understand that public DNS will not resolve it, but I'm not trying to access it from a normal SSH. It's torified, which is why I expected Tor to resolve it just as it resolves onion addresses even though public DNS does not. I do know about SSH config, and I have used that before even so much as to put the ncat proxy so that I don't need `torify`, but only on my own computer. In this case, I don't even know which computer I would be using, so adding to the config is just as inconvenient as using the onion address manually.

Comment: The issue is because `torsocks` when you enter a .com address *goes over General DNS*.  THAT fails to lookup properly, it's not a "Oh, go to this onion address", it's a "Go to the IP address that this other hostname references", torsocks **never sees the .onion alias** because that's not returned in a DNS lookup for a `.com` that's CNAME'd, only the A or AAAA record for the CNAME destination is actually 'returned', or NXDOMAIN (which is the case for .ONIONs).  Which is why I gave you the crash-course in DNS mechanics here.

Comment: Okay; that makes sense. So then if this were a website, I could use an A record to resolve to a server that then uses a 301 to the onion address, which is a common enough service from DNS providers. But there really isn't a way to do an alias like that for SSH, is there? I'm thinking what I want is probably just impossible, but I don't know if there's another option I haven't thought of.

Comment: @zondo The end of my post gives you an SSH solution that *should* be able to automatically make the .com look to the .onion as the actual hostname.  I can't guarantee it'll work, but you can try it.  Otherwise, no, there's no other mechanism you have here to work with unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

plain dns no.. how about saving in txt record and wrap the call like

```
torify ssh $(dig +short example.com -t txt)
```